# Erro with Merge plugin in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: plugins, merge, crm

I'm facing by problem in my plugin to Dynamics CRM 2013 Service Pack 1 (SP1) (6.1.0.581) (DB 6.1.0.581) On-Premises, the plugin fires on Merge post-operation Sync

I have one "InvalidPluginExecutionException" in my code that have a custom message, but in CRM the plugin show a generic message "ISV code aborted the operation", I performed research on the subject and the people recommended to update the Rollup do most recently version, that's true? anyone did this and it worked ?

Comment: I Assume, you are throwing out the custom message via InvalidPluginExecutionException and not the general Exception.

Comment: Please post your code and what you wish to accomplish with the plugin

Comment: Any code that I input in Merge message give that generic error,

for exemple:

try
            {
                 throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("test");
            }

Comment: I really think that this error give in SP1 Dynamics 2013 like this post comment [link]https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/154712
But I'm  not sure if that's true, because I'm not find nothing official document from Microsoft talking about this, only in 2011 - [link]https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2739504
"Custom error messages for software development kit (SDK) plug-ins are not displayed as expected. Instead, a generic error message that states that ISV code aborted the operation is displayed."

Comment: I have another 2013 Dynamics environment with 6.1.3 Rollup with the same plugin code and that message not showed